# Why does if condition not working? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUREST_URI']

Tags: php, url

I am trying to display different word on each url.

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($host=="www.thesofacompany.ca/index.php?route=information/contact"){
    echo "A";
}
if($host=="www.thesofacompany.ca/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=4") //This if statement isn't working..
{
    echo "B";
}
```

This is the if statement I've used.. But the second if statement is not working. The program skips the second if statement even when $host has the correct strings..

Does special character & makes it not working?

Comment: `if($host=="http://www.thesofacompany.ca...`

Comment: @Fred-ii- The scheme isn't a part of the server name.

Comment: do an echo after $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; and see the connect of $host

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol My mistake; I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but the string comparison is case sensitive so if the url has incorrect case, it will evaluate to false.  If you are hosting on IIS, this can be a problem since IIS is case insensitive.  You might want to try :

```
$host = strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if($host=="www.thesofacompany.ca/index.php?route=information/contact"){
echo "A";
}
if($host=="www.thesofacompany.ca/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=4") //This if statement isn't working..
{
echo "B";
}
```

This will just make sure you have a lowercase string to compare against.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on server variables, you should instead use the parameters you are given.

Namely, it's fairly safe to assume you're working on `index.php` anyway, and if the server name were wrong then you'd be on a completely different website.

So your `if` should be:

```
if( isset($_GET['route'],$_GET['information'])
 && $_GET['route'] == "information/information"
 && $_GET['information'] == 4) {
    echo "B";
}
```